# android - animate on swipe

Tags: java, android, animation, swipe

In my new program I need objects that can be swiped to the side. I already have my animation, which is working and I tried to detect the swiping of the user in another class. The problem I have is that I don't know how to connect them. When the swipe gesture is correctly recognized a specific animation should start.

My AnimatedViewClass:

```
private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(continueAnimation) {
            invalidate(); 
            }
        }
    };


    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {  

                if (x<0) {
                    x = this.getWidth()/2-100;
                    y = this.getHeight()/2-100;
                } 

                    else {
                        x += xVelocity;

                            if ((x > this.getWidth() - ball.getBitmap().getWidth()) || (x < 0)) {
                                boolean continueAnimation = false;
                            }
                    }

                c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null);  

                if(continueAnimation) 
                {
                    h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);
                }   

                else {
                        x = this.getWidth()-ball.getBitmap().getWidth();
                }

            }
```

My SwipeTouchListener:

```
    public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;
                } 
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `GestureDetector` to your view class just like this, and replace your code inside `onFling()`

```
public class AnimatedViewClass extends View {

GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public AnimatedViewClass(Context context) {
    super(context);
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new GestureDetectorListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private void onSwipeRight(){
    // swipe right detected
    // do stuff
    invalidate();
}


private void onSwipeLeft(){
    // swipe left detected
    // do stuff
    invalidate();
}

private class GestureDetectorListener extends
        GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        // onSwipeRight()
        // onSwipeLeft()

        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return super.onDown(e);
    }
}


private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(continueAnimation) {
            invalidate();
        }
    }
};


protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {

    if (x < 0) {
        x = this.getWidth() / 2 - 100;
        y = this.getHeight() / 2 - 100;
    } else {
        x += xVelocity;

        if ((x > this.getWidth() - ball.getBitmap().getWidth()) || (x < 0)) {
            boolean continueAnimation = false;
        }
    }

    c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null);

    if (continueAnimation) {
        h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);
    } else {
        x = this.getWidth() - ball.getBitmap().getWidth();
    }

}


}
```

Comment: Does the GestureDetector recogize different directions? And do i call the animation in `onSwipeRight` e.g. or can i set specific animations in these methods?

Comment: Yes exactly, do whatever you wanna do inside onSwipeRight, like running your desired animation.

Comment: Perfect, i'll try it. What is the `invalidate();` method in the swipe method for?

Comment: It refreshes the view and calls onDraw(), you can remove it if you don't need it.

Comment: So it does the same like the runnable method in my code?

Comment: Yup, sorry I didn't see that.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your help I'll try it out

Comment: I'm glad to help!

Comment: @Khaled5 I'm a little lost: how do I call my animation `protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {...}`method inside the `private void onSwipeRight`? I can't just paste the whole part into it, so how am I starting it from there?

Comment: Well it depends on what you're trying to do. From what I see you're drawing something in onDraw, therefore change the values (probably x? or velocityX) from the methods (e.g onSwipeRight), and call invalidate, this will execute the code inside onDraw with the updated values.

Comment: Yes, that's what it should do, there's no error, but the app crashes anyway

Comment: May you tell me how I delete my image object after the animation, so i can create a new one? Do I use `animation.cancel();`?

Comment: I don't get how to cancel the animation, because cancel() or clearAnimation() are not defined for that animator

Comment: That's a completely different question, so please ask another question, and I'll try answering it.

Comment: No, this question has been answered, start a new one, please.